# php Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Im getting this error

```
Call to a member function query() on null
```

[Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992830/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-null)

[Call to member function query() on Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162877/call-to-member-function-query-on-null)

But neither seems to solve my problem

I have db class

```
class DB
{
    private $link;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
        if ($this->link->connect_error) 
        {
            exit('Some of the database login credentials seem to be wrong.' . $this->link->connect_error);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I attempt to query the database with this class

```
class UserModel extends DB
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getUser();
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        var_dump($query);
    }
}
```

These files are in site/app/model/file.php

I instantiate db in my site/index.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of errors here:

1. As you define own construct in `UserModel` class, parent `__construct`, where `$link` var is defined, is not run. You can add `parent::__construct();` to child constructor.
2. In your parent class you have `$link` variable, not `$db`. And `$link` is `private`, so it's not avaialble in child classes.

Fixed code is

```
class DB
{
    protected $link;   // protected here

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
        if ($this->link->connect_error) 
        {
            exit('Some of the database login credentials seem to be wrong.' . $this->link->connect_error);
        }
    }
}


class UserModel extends DB
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // call parent construct and define $this->link
        parent::__construct();  
        $this->getUser();
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        // use $this->link
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        var_dump($query);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform

> private $link

To

> protected $link

This allows the child class to have access to such variable.

And of course, make use of the `$this->link` instead of the `$this->db`